# how can we style string we have from array join ?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a scenario where once user select multiple owners from modal window and i am displaying all selected owners on the screen with `;` separator, So my question is can i add some background color to each of these item instead of using separator so user can see the difference in the names.

html

```
<input type="text" class="form-control mousedwncall"
        id="cntrlOwner" required ng-model="controlDTO.cntrlOwner"
        name="cntrlOwner"
        ng-click="opencntrlOwner()"
        placeholder="Control Owner" />
```

ctrl.js

```
 $scope.selectedControlOwner = function() {
       $scope.ctrlOwnerModal.close();
       $scope.createControlFormName.$dirty=true;
       $scope.controlDTO.controlOwnerWorkerKey = $scope.selectedOwners.map(function (owner) { return owner.workerKey; });
       $scope.controlDTO.cntrlOwner = $scope.selectedOwners.map(function (owner) { return owner.fullName; }).join(';');
     };
```

Comment: You can't style portions of an `<input>` element's value. You can style the whole thing though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [select2](https://select2.github.io/). When you choose multiple values, it shows them as a list of closable items inside something that looks like a text input. As an example go [here](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#programmatic) and press 'Set to California and Alabama'

Comment: this link was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the concatenated list of names, you can simply store the list. Then in your template, you can `ng-repeat` over this list and store each name in a `<span>` (or some other element), which you can then style:

```
$scope.controlDTO.cntrlOwners = $scope.selectedOwners.map(function (owner) { return owner.fullName; });
```

Then in your markup:

```
<div>
  <span class="owner" ng-repeat="owner in controlDTO.ctrlOwners">{{owner}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add some detail?